# Why does Cygwin repeat every command I type?

Tags: unix, directory, cygwin

Every time I type a command into cygwin, it repeats it, with a plus sign before it. It's not the biggest deal but it just bothers me.

It looks like this:

```
Julian@JuliansASUS /cygdrive/c/Users/Julian/dev
$ mkdir play
+ mkdir play

Julian@JuliansASUS /cygdrive/c/Users/Julian/dev
$ ls
+ ls
autoHotKey  gitp1   play   TopCoder.jnlp


Julian@JuliansASUS /cygdrive/c/Users/Julian/dev
$
```

What's going on?
Btdubs this is bash

Thanks!

Comment: you have debugging mode turned on. search for `set -x` in your bash_rc files OR on the cmdline, just type `set +x`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thr ya go! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the shell's debugging mode turned on.

To turn it off from the cmdline: just type `set +x`.

If this fixes the problem, but the next time you open a terminal window the problem returns, then search for `set -x` in your `bash_rc` files and delete it (or comment it out).

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
~/.bash_profile 
~/.bash.login
~/.profile
~/.login
~/bash.bashrc 
~/.bashrc
```

Is a reasonably complete list that would effect just your command line. For ksh and zsh users, substitute `bash` with `ksh` or `zsh` and start looking!

But any script can contain reference to its own config files OR just contains `set =x` (and possibly related and `set x`. So if you only see the duplicate output with a leading `+` sign when running a script, you'll have to search through the script or any sub-scripts.

IHTH